# Getting PermissionError while saving BERT model checkpoint

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-trainer

I am finetuning a BERT model for classification task,
Following code is used for the training the model.

```
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments, AutoConfig
from transformers import Trainer

batch_size = 8
logging_steps = len(emotions_encoded['train']) // batch_size
print(len(emotions_encoded['train']))
print(logging_steps)

model_name = f"BERT-emotion-classification"

# Create a configuration object
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(model_ckpt, output_hidden_states=True)

# Save the configuration to a JSON file
config.to_json_file(f"{model_name}/config.json")

training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir=model_name,
                                        num_train_epochs=2,
                                        learning_rate=2e-5,
                                        per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
                                        per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
                                        weight_decay=0.01,
                                        evaluation_strategy="epoch",
                                        disable_tqdm=False,
                                        logging_steps=logging_steps,
                                        push_to_hub=True,
                                        log_level="error")


trainer = Trainer(model=model, args=training_args,
                                compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
                                train_dataset=emotions_encoded["train"],
                                eval_dataset=emotions_encoded["validation"],
                                tokenizer=tokenizer)
trainer.train();

# Save the model using Trainer's save_model method
trainer.save_model(f"./{model_name}")
```

Train runs fine till the first checkpoint is created and then PermissionError is thrown.

```
{
    "name": "PermissionError",
    "message": "[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'BERT-emotion-classification\\\\checkpoint-500'",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[34], line 7
      1 from transformers import Trainer
      2 trainer = Trainer(model=model, args=training_args,
      3                                 compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
      4                                 train_dataset=emotions_encoded[\"train\"],
      5                                 eval_dataset=emotions_encoded[\"validation\"],
      6                                 tokenizer=tokenizer)
----> 7 trainer.train();
      9 # Save the model using Trainer's save_model method
     10 trainer.save_model(f\"./{model_name}\")

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'BERT-emotion-classification\\\\checkpoint-500'"
}
```

I checked the folder has the all the permission.

Comment: Have you tried simply using only the `training_args.output_dir`? Then `save_model()` should work out of the box. The answer below shows that indeed there might be an issue with the source code currently.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [discussion on HF](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/permission-issues-when-saving-model-checkpoint/70109/2) that solves this issue.

> I simply remove those lines of line. In this example, I basically removed lines 2417-2420. It appears to still work for me.

Comment: It would be good to explain what is proposed in the HF forum and share the proposed code changes directly here.